# font size change onclick for more than on div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 10 div and when any one click on any div and then click on increment button then font size of that div should be increase.

It is working for single div. But I need for more than one div.
When I remove getDate(), then it is working for one div.

I have to click on div and then click on increment or decrement tag.Then font size of that div should be  increment or decrement.

```js
function getDate(e) {
  var originalSize = $('#' + e).css('font-size');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  //var originalSize = $('div').css('font-size');   

  $('#linkIncrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('increase');
  });

  $('#linkDecrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('decrease');
  });

  $('#linkReset').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('reset');
  })

  function modifyFontSize(flag) {
    var divElement = $('#divContent');
    var currentFontSize = parseInt(divElement.css('font-size'));

    if (flag == 'increase')
      currentFontSize += 1;
    else if (flag == 'decrease')
      currentFontSize -= 1;
    else
      currentFontSize = 16;

    divElement.css('font-size', currentFontSize);
  }
});
```

```css
.divClass {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="linkIncrease" href="#"><b>+</b></a>

<a id="linkDecrease" href="#"><b>-</b></a>

<a id="linkReset" href="#"> <b>X</b></a>

<br /> <br />
<div id="divContent" class="divClass" onClick="getDate(this.id);"> Hello </div>
<br>
<div id="divContent1" class="divClass" onClick="getDate(this.id);"> Hello </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. ALWAYS use https for jQuery, I had to change to https to make your script run. 1.11 is a VERY old version

Comment: It is working only for 1st div. But when I click on second div. Then it is not working. How to do this?

Comment: Change to `var divElement = $('.divClass');`

Comment: Sorry I see your issue is not unique IDs it is that you only ever choose divContent and not the clicked div. ASSUMING you want to increas ALL divs, use the class. If you only want to increase the clicked div, we need to change your code

Comment: please give me solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version that increases only CLICKED div

It saves the original size on the div itself in a data attribute

I also bail out if nothing was clicked before plus or minus are clicked

```js
let divElement;

function modifyFontSize(flag) {
  let $divElement = $("#" + divElement);
  if ($divElement.length === 0) console.log("Nothing selected")
  let currentFontSize = parseInt($divElement.css('font-size'));

  if (flag == 'increase')
    currentFontSize += 1;
  else if (flag == 'decrease')
    currentFontSize -= 1;
  else
    currentFontSize = $divElement.data("orgSize") || 16;

  $divElement.css('font-size', currentFontSize);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".divClass").on("click", function() {
    divElement = this.id;
    if (!$(this).data("orgSize")) $(this).data("orgSize", $(this).css('font-size'))
  })
  $('#linkIncrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('increase');
  });

  $('#linkDecrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('decrease');
  });

  $('#linkReset').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('reset');
  })

});
```

```css
.divClass {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="linkIncrease" href="#"><b>+</b></a>

<a id="linkDecrease" href="#"><b>-</b></a>

<a id="linkReset" href="#"> <b>X</b></a>

<br /> <br />
<div id="divContent" class="divClass"> Hello </div>
<br>
<div id="divContent1" class="divClass"> Hello </div>
```

Comment: This is working on all div at a time. But I need it on only clicked div. not all div.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
let divId = '';

function getDate(e) {
  var originalSize = $('#' + e).css('font-size');
  divId = e;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  //var originalSize = $('div').css('font-size');   

  $('#linkIncrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('increase');
  });

  $('#linkDecrease').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('decrease');
  });

  $('#linkReset').click(function() {
    modifyFontSize('reset');
  })

  function modifyFontSize(flag) {
    
    var divElement = $(`#${divId}`);
    var currentFontSize = parseInt(divElement.css('font-size'));

    if (flag == 'increase')
      currentFontSize += 1;
    else if (flag == 'decrease')
      currentFontSize -= 1;
    else
      currentFontSize = 16;

    divElement.css('font-size', currentFontSize);
  }
});
```

```css
.divClass {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="linkIncrease" href="#"><b>+</b></a>

<a id="linkDecrease" href="#"><b>-</b></a>

<a id="linkReset" href="#"> <b>X</b></a>

<br /> <br />
<div id="divContent" class="divClass" onClick="getDate(this.id);"> Hello </div>
<br>
<div id="divContent1" class="divClass" onClick="getDate(this.id);"> Hello </div>
```

I added a variable 'divId' to store the selected div when the function getDate() is called. Then I apply font-sizing to that div only.

Comment: Your reset does not work. See my solution for one that does. We need to store the original size before resizing on the first click